# Splitting routes into separate files

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am developing a Vue app which is quite big, and I now I have to write all the routes on one page in `router/index.js` and it is already becoming too long to like or even maintain. The `index.js` page is full of statements like...

```
import This from '../components/This'
import That from '../components/That'
import ThatOther from '../components/ThatOther'
import ThatOtherOne from '../components/ThatOtherOne'
// and so on and so on...then at the bottom
var router = new Router({                  
routes: [
    {
        path: '/this', 
        name: 'this', 
        component: This
    },
    {
        path: '/that', 
        name: 'that', 
        component: That
    },
// and so on...so many lines of similar and "repetitive" code
```

Since my app can be grouped into "modules", is there a way to split the routes into separate files (both the `import` statements and the router entries) in like `router/this.js`,`router/that.js...', then add them to the main route page,`router/index.js`?

Comment: `routes` is just an array of route objects. You can export as many route arrays as you want and concatenate them together before adding them to the router.

Comment: Thanks! The example in the answer hit it even better!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In a seperate file:

```
import This from '../components/This'
import That from '../components/That'
import ThatOther from '../components/ThatOther'
import ThatOtherOne from '../components/ThatOtherOne'

export default [
  {
        path: '/this', 
        name: 'this', 
        component: This
    },
    {
        path: '/that', 
        name: 'that', 
        component: That
    },
]
```

in your route file import the external routes and use the [spread oeprator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals):

```
import externalRoutesOne from './externalRoutesOne'
import externalRoutesTwo from './externalRoutesTwo'
var router = new Router({                  
routes: [
  ...externalRoutesOne,
  ...externalRoutesTwo
]
```

> **Note:** the `...` operator is required when defining them routes.

Comment: The above looks ok,but gives the error `[vue-router] "path" is required in a route configuration`. in the `routes` property of Router, I need to merge the separate routes into a single array or?

Comment: I merged after importing them using the `concat` function, then used the end result at the `routes` property. 
`var routes = This.concat(That)
   .concat(ThatOther)
   .concat(ThatOtherOne);

var router = new Router({                  
 routes: routes
}); `

Would love to know if there is a more "learned" way :)

Comment: There is no need to use concat, the spread operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) does exactly that, as shown in my example. I'm currently on the go but I will verify my provided code once I'm home to make sure it works.

Comment: OK, ok, I'm daft! I must confess that I had ignored the `...` at the beginning of the name. Never thought it means anything. Now I know better. That said, your code works perfectly. Bravo!

Comment: Note: the ... operator is required when defining them routes.

Comment: thx, works flawlessly !!!